# Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' in your configuration

Tags: api, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm trying to connect an API witha postgres database. And for that, I'm using Spring Boot.
When testing the api, i keep getting the error

> Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' in your configuration.

I understand that i need a `@Bean` for `ServletController`, but I donw know exactly what this bean should do. When i made a generic one, but then the console told me to revisit it. I have no idea what to do here, and stackoverflow hasn't helped either.

Here's my Application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SwaggerDefinition
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableConfigurationProperties(XXXXConfiguracaoApplication.class)
public class FonumS3ApiApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XXXXApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
       return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
         .select()                                  
         .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
         .paths(PathSelectors.any()) 
         .build()
         .apiInfo(apiInfo());                                           
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
         return new ApiInfo(
             "API XXXX", 
             "API XXXX para integrações entre sistemas.", 
             "API V1", 
             "Terms of service", 
             new Contact("XXXX", "www.XXXX.com", "XXXX.XXXX@XXXX.com"), 
             "License of XXX", "API license URL", Collections.emptyList());
        }
    }
}
```

(the annotations are there, but for some reason, the stackoverflow did not accept them) and my pom is

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What does the test look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have excluded Tomcat from web and added Tomcat provided scope so I assume you are trying to create war and deploy on external Tomcat, so you have to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override `configure` method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SwaggerDefinition
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableConfigurationProperties(XXXXConfiguracaoApplication.class)
public class FonumS3ApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XXXXApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
       return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
         .select()                                  
         .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
         .paths(PathSelectors.any()) 
         .build()
         .apiInfo(apiInfo());                                           
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
         return new ApiInfo(
             "API XXXX", 
             "API XXXX para integrações entre sistemas.", 
             "API V1", 
             "Terms of service", 
             new Contact("XXXX", "www.XXXX.com", "XXXX.XXXX@XXXX.com"), 
             "License of XXX", "API license URL", Collections.emptyList());
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you are running with embedded Tomcat then don't change anything in main class and remove `exclusion` from web and remove Tomcat jar:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and remove Tomcat jar below:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```